# Access Audit Inspection + History block!

Tags: ms-access, inspection

**Objective:**

```
- electronic form which displays 45 inspection points (rarely changes)
- 3 additional columns
  - Rating (0, 1, 2)
  - CorrectiveAction (Immediate, SOP, WO)
  - Notes
- Maintain inspection history
  - inspection date, production line inspected, production shift-crew inspected
```

Tables:

```
- Employee (empID (auto#), FName, LName, Shift, Line)
- Audit Facts (ID#, textdescrip)   tried with and without autonumber
- Audit Details (auditID (auto#), auditdate, rating, action, notes)  *(rating/action combobox)
```

A subform in a form has the 45 check points all tied to the Audit number.  However, I cannot get the audit results to record, store and move into history.

every attempt i've made produces an audit number PER each 45 checkpts, as opposed to

```
 Audit Date
   AuditID(auto#)
      AuditFact (list of 45 chckpts)
```

results

```
        Audit1, 10/02/2010 ->
           *AuditPt     Rate     Action*        
                IF1          0      WO
                IF2          2      SOP
                ... 
                IF45         1      Immediate

        Audit2, 12/15/2010 ->
           *AuditPt     Rate     Action*        
                IF1          1      WO
                IF2          0      SOP
                ... 
                IF45         0      Immediate
```

Comment: I am still having problems understanding this. Are you familiar with ms-access?

Answer (score 0):

Get your tables right & your forms will follow.

The original question isn't entirely clear, but I *think* I got these points:

1. An "Audit" is the same as an "Inspection"
2. The *collection* of 45 "inspection points" constitutes an Audit (not each one individually).
3. "Ratings" and "Actions" apply to *each* inspeciton point.

So your tables want to be more like this:

```
Audit
  AuditId (can be autonumber, or not...)
  AuditDate

AuditItem
  AuditItemId (can be autonumber, or not...)
  AuditId (FK from Audit)
  InspPoint (e.g., the "IF1" from the "result" sample, or--better--an FK to it another table)
  Rating
  Action (Or--better--an FK to it another table)
```

Table "Employee" seems entirely irrelevant to this strucure.

Note that each Insection Point has its own row in AuditItem, *for each Audit*, and that those rows also carry the AuditID from Audit, which lets you pull them all together to make you output.

Hopefully this will make sense--if it doesn't, I recommend reviewing [fundamental relational database design](http://www.databaseanswers.org/tutorial4_db_schema/index.htm).

Comment: thank you-tried tbls for each Rating, Action, Employee, InspectionPts...but no success in history retention.  Employees are relevant mainly for Shift and ProductionLine (inspections performed daily for two shifts and 4 production lines = 8 inspections/day)

Comment: So, Employee Ids may need to be added to the Audit table--which *has history built in*. Check the link.

Comment: after all these yrs of Accessdesign and this 'simple' dbase has been a battle for near a month....and still, the table 'trees' do not expand out.